# JPA 2.0 BI directional one-to-one mapping merge

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA 2 with hibernate as the vendor.
I have 2 entities, Group and GroupFilter. I have a one-to-one bidirectional mapping between them with a join column in GroupFilter referencing Group. While saving Group, the GroupFilter gets persisted.
However, when i try to update Group using merge, i get  - 
 org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance

While persisting group, i need to set both relations explicitly. Using the mappedBy attribute on Group, the order of save is that Group gets persisted 1st, and then GroupFilter.
But in the case of merge, i think it happens the other way around. (cascade = ALL).

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Here are the associations - 
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE,mappedBy="groupid",orphanRemoval=true)
private DynamicGroupFilter dynamicGroupFilter;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="groupid",referencedColumnName="key")
private Group groupid;

and I do something like this before a persist/merge
dynamicGroupFilter.setGroup(group)
and then group.setDynamicGroupFilter(dynamicGroupFilter)

It actually seems like a circular reference to me, but this is how i got the persist to work.
Unfortunately, merge does not seem to be OK with this